# Why select do not tell me that a client wants to connect?

Tags: linux, tcp, sockets

I've made a simple tcp server that I can test with `telnet` program.

When running it on windows, it works as expected, when running it on linux, the behavior is strange:

- telnet clients understand that they are connected to the server,
- the server do not see clients (`select` return always `0`),
- when I kill the server, the clients detect the disconnection.

I think I missed something in `accept`, `listen` or `select`.

What did I missed?

Thanks.

Here's the program source:

```
#include "headers.h"
#define DEFAULT_PORT 24891

/**
 * test_server [ip port]
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sockaddr_in sin;
    socket_t sock;

    /* listening socket creation */
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (-1 == sock)
        { die("socket()"); }        

    /* binding */
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sin.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);
    if (3 == argc)
    {
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
        sin.sin_port = htons(strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0));
    }

    if (-1 == bind(sock, (sockaddr*) &sin, sizeof(sin)))
        { die("bind()"); }

    /* Listening */
    if (-1 == listen(sock, SOMAXCONN))
        { die("listen()"); }     

    while (1)
    {
        timeval timeout = { 1, 0 };
        fd_set in_set;

        FD_ZERO(&in_set);
        FD_SET(sock, &in_set);

        // select the set
        int cnt = select(1, &in_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            // ask if an event occurs on listening socket
            if (FD_ISSET(sock, &in_set))
            {
                /* a new client wants to connect */
                socket_t csock = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);

                send(csock, "hello\r\n", 7, 0);
                printf("new client!\n");

                close(csock);                
            }
        }     
        else if (cnt < 0)
            { die("select"); }

    }

    /* closing listen socket */
    close(sock);
    printf("socket closed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply call select incorrectly. The first parameter needs to be the highest numbered fd from the fdset, plus one. See man page:

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
....

nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets,  plus 1.
```

The code may work, or may not, that depends on the fd returned by "socket()".

In your case the value of "nfds" needs to be "sock + 1", generally you need to track the highest numbered fd when doing a select on multiple fd's.

Comment: In the same way, I understand that it worked on Windows because this parameter is ignored (in Windows).